# Generate Bitcoin addresses using a Master Key from Armory wallet

Tags: address, armory, php, address-generation

Is it possible to generate Bitcoin addresses using a Master Key from a Armory wallet with PHP?

I don't want to use Electrum Master Key as Armory has a lot more features that come in handy often.

Comment: Do you have the ability to install software on this server, or is it a shared hosting environment?

Comment: @NickODell I can install software but I'd rather not.